# Existing Layer 2 in Smartpy or Archetype

Tags: smartpy

Is there an existing Layer 2 solution for Smartpy or Archetype? Just like There is [Deku](https://www.marigold.dev/deku) from Marigold in Ligo?

The only thing I could find i Deku, but I work mostly with Smartpy or Archetype?

By the way.. I tried to add Archetype as tag but it seems such a tag does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deku-p is a Tezos sidechain framework written in OCaml.
Deku-c is an implementation of a Deku-p sidechain with a WASM VM.

You can run smartcontrat written in wat or Ligo thanks to ligo to wasm compilation toolchain.
In beta, those are the only tested contracts, later any wasm contract would be supported.

If you want to use Deku with Smartpy or Archetype, depending of the objective to achieve, one can either implement a Deku-p sidechain with a Michelson VM (huge work) or have a wasm compilation toolchain to run in Deku-c

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. Why is it called Deku-p and Deku-c? Is there a reason for the ending letter p and c? So Marigold implemented both Deku-p and c? Is there a documentation page like the tezos gitlab or something else?

Comment: Deku-p stands for Deku Parametric and Deku-c for Deku Canonical (cause it is the canonical implementation of a blockchain with the framework). 
Both are developped by Marigold.
Doc: https://deku.marigold.dev/docs/intro

Comment: Great thanks for the link!